# I have to implement design like below image in android

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, android-listview

[image]

I need to implement a design like this. I have tried Grid but i cant achieve this design. Primary goal is to show a List of Strings in the given design and select one from list.

`val layoutManagersituation = GridLayoutManager(this, 3) layoutManagersituation.spanSizeLookup = object : SpanSizeLookup() { override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int { return 3 - position % 3 } }`

Comment: You can use this library : https://github.com/greenfrvr/hashtag-view

Comment: Post your code.